# chef-solo example

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

We are learning chef-solo and need a good example for better understanding.. Have searched a lot on net but the ideas are very confusing. can anyone suggest some examples.. and also how to run them.. We have installed chef-0.8.16 gem but couldnt figure out how to work with it.. We are using windows platform..Its urgent..

Comment: Very sane chef-solo tutorial is written by [opinionated programmer](http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/06/chef-solo-tutorial-managing-a-single-server-with-chef/).

Answer (score 1):

Windows platform support is quite new ([version 0.8.14](http://www.opscode.com/blog/2010/05/07/chef-0-8-14-release/)), so its ability to configure resources on Windows is fairly limited until the next release which will add new resource providers for the platform.

A good resource for Chef Solo is its [page on the Wiki](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Solo). You can also get help from the [IRC channel](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/IRC) and [mailing lists](http://lists.opscode.com).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a bootstrap script here for testing out chef-solo in ec2. It includes a very trivial recipe to run also.

https://github.com/conormullen/chef-bootstrap

for more complex recipes you could have a look here:

https://github.com/opscode/chef